# Fetching image using Picasso

Tags: java, android

Here in the given below code, I am trying to display in the image in recyclerview in the imageview after fetching it using picasso, it won't show error or app won't crash either but image won't be displayed, it either shows:

**"I/Choreographer: Skipped 30 frames! The application may be doing too much work on its main thread."**

**Or**

**W/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout**

public class Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Adapter.ViewHolder> {

```
LayoutInflater inflater;
List<Lists> lst;
private ItemClickListsner mItemListener;


public Adapter(Context ctx, List<Lists> lst, ItemClickListsner itemClickListsner) {
    this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(ctx);
    this.lst = lst;
    this.mItemListener = itemClickListsner;

}


@NonNull
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_list, parent, false);

    return new ViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    //   final Lists temp = lst.get(position);

    holder.id.setText(lst.get(position).getId());
    holder.name.setText(lst.get(position).getName());
    holder.prc.setText(lst.get(position).getPrc());
    holder.add.setText(lst.get(position).getAddress());
    holder.description.setText(lst.get(position).getDes());
    holder.park.setText(lst.get(position).getGarage());
    holder.net.setText(lst.get(position).getNet());
    holder.email.setText(lst.get(position).getMail());
    holder.number.setText(lst.get(position).getPnumber());
    holder.post.setText(lst.get(position).getTle());
    holder.date.setText(lst.get(position).getCrt());

    Picasso.with(inflater.getContext())
            .load(lst.get(position).getMimage())
            .placeholder(R.drawable.bed)
            .fit()
            .into(holder.ImgView);

    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(view -> {
        mItemListener.onItemClick(lst.get(position));
    });

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return lst.size();
}

public interface ItemClickListsner{
    void onItemClick(Lists lst);
}

public void filterList(ArrayList<Lists> filteredList) {
    lst = filteredList;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView id, name, add, prc, description, park, net, post,email,number,date;
    ImageView ImgView;
    //  CardView cardView;


    public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        id = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewRecy1);
        name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewRecy2);
        prc = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewRecy3);
        add = itemView.findViewById((R.id.textViewRecy4));
        description = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewRecy5);
        park = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewRecy6);
        net = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewRecy7);
        post = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewRecy8);
        email = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewRecy9);
        number = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewRecy10);
        date = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewRecy11);
        ImgView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ImageRecy);

    }
}
```

}

**Activity Code**

private void extractList() {
RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

```
    JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET, JSON_URL, null, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
            for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = response.getJSONObject(i);
                    //Log.d("tags", "error: " + jsonObject);

                    Lists lists = new Lists();

                    lists.setName(jsonObject.getString("title").toString());
                    lists.setAddress(jsonObject.getString("location").toString());
                    lists.setPrc(jsonObject.getString("price").toString());
                    lists.setDes(jsonObject.getString("description").toString());
                    lists.setGarage(jsonObject.getString("parking").toString());
                    lists.setNet(jsonObject.getString("internet").toString());
                    lists.setMail(jsonObject.getString("email").toString());
                    lists.setPnumber(jsonObject.getString("phone_number").toString());
                    lists.setTle(jsonObject.getString("poster").toString());
                    lists.setCrt(jsonObject.getString("created").toString());
                    lists.setMimage(jsonObject.getString("photo1").toString());

                   String p = jsonObject.getString("photo1").toString();

                   Log.e("kk","msg"+p);

                    lst.add(lists);

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


            }

             recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext()));
            adapter = new Adapter(getApplicationContext(), lst, new Adapter.ItemClickListsner() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(Lists lst) {
                  //  startActivity(new Intent(HomeActivity.this,roomsDesc.class));
                    Intent intent = new Intent(HomeActivity.this, roomsDesc.class);
                    intent.putExtra("title",lst.getName());
                    intent.putExtra("price",lst.getPrc());
                    intent.putExtra("location",lst.getAddress());
                    intent.putExtra("description",lst.getDes());
                    intent.putExtra("parking",lst.getGarage());
                    intent.putExtra("internet",lst.getNet());
                    intent.putExtra("email",lst.getMail());
                    intent.putExtra("phone_number",lst.getPnumber());
                    intent.putExtra("poster",lst.getTle());
                    intent.putExtra("created",lst.getCrt());
                    intent.putExtra("photo1",lst.getMimage());

                    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    HomeActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

        }
```

Comment: Need to see adapter and fragment code if you want help, I can't see anything wrong with the code you put there so far.

Comment: Can you check now?